# Resizing Actual MapView - not contents in mapview

Tags: android, view, resize, android-mapview

I'm trying to resize my MapView when a user clicks a certain button (ie - go from a mapview a quarter of the screen size to full screen size) however I do not know how to do it!

I've tried `mMapView.setLayoutParams(new MapView.LayoutParams(250, 250, 0, 0, 6));` but that only gives me errors (ClassCastException).

I can't think of anything else (and searching has not come up with much).

Comment: I see that the parameter of setLayoutParams is a View not a MapView. Perhaps that is the reason for your ClassCastException.

Comment: @mozillanerd It's not a View. It's a LayoutParams object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        MapView map = new MapView(this, "");
        map.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        map.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));
```

By the way as a general rule, never use absolute positioning (250 pixels) to do anything in Android - it'll cause problems when used on different devices. Use relative layouts, or at the very least device independent pixels (dip). So for example you could set the layout_width to wrap_content, the layout_weight of the MapView to 1 (so it stetches to fill the available space), and then place another UI element to its side, taking up some of the space, and the map will then reduce in size.

Comment: I've just created a test project and it works fine for me, so you're obviously doing something else that breaks it. I've updated my example to show you exactly what works for me.

Comment: If you still have problems I'd split up the statement you're using, to create the LayaoutParams on one line, and apply it on another.

Comment: 'works' now that I don't have a mapview already set in my layout file (but no map shows up now...) - but those are just details :D - I'll mark as correct