# Re-sizing Google Maps and using address entered from EditText on Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So, as part of my app that I am making, I have an EditText field on my screen in which the user will input an address, but what I would like for my app to do is have a smaller size Google Map which will be on the same screen as my EditText which recieves the address, and also displays the current location of the entered address. How would I go about doing that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far for implementing above functionality? First you try & then post things where you get stuck. This is totally wrong way you followed.

Comment: You are right. Well, so far, I have been able to put a map on a screen, and I looked at some resources for resizing the map, but I have not been able to get it to work too much to how I would like. @RIT

Comment: I believe this link will help you to resize mapview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550008/resizing-actual-mapview-not-contents-in-mapview